# Python: Converting from Tuple to String?

Tags: python, string, tuples

let's say that I have string:

```
    s = "Tuple: "
```

and Tuple (stored in a variable named tup):

```
    (2, a, 5)
```

I'm trying to get my string to contain the value "Tuple: (2, a, 5)". I noticed that you can't just concatenate them. Does anyone know the most straightforward way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This also works:

```
>>> s = "Tuple: " + str(tup)
>>> s
"Tuple: (2, 'a', 5)"
```

Comment: Yes, this is definitely the most straightforward way!

Answer (score 11):

Try joining the tuple. We need to use map(str, tup) as some of your values are integers, and join only accepts strings.

```
s += "(" + ', '.join(map(str,tup)) + ")"
```

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> tup = (2, "a", 5)
>>> s = "Tuple: {}".format(tup)
>>> s
"Tuple: (2, 'a', 5)"
```

Comment: Why does the {} need to be in there?

Comment: For instance, what if I just wanted it to be "Tuple (2, a, 5)" instead of "Tuple: (2, a, 5)" with a colon?

Comment: @JacobGriffin, use a format string --> http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format, try the code

Comment: The `{}` is a format specifier, look up how python string formatting works. It means to interpolate a passed argument to the string. Since there's only one of these, it specifically means the first argument.

Comment: Thanks, user :) Thank you Crast