# Python list of tuples with variable length: Get string representation of tuples holding only object attributes

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples that consist of objects of a certain class and differ in their dimension:

```
my_list = [(obj1, obj2), (obj3, obj1), (obj4, obj1), (obj2,),...]
```

All of these objects have an attribute `label` which is of type `string` and holds an object label e.g. `'object_1'`, `'object_2'` and so on.

Now I want to extract the string representation of the tuples holding the attribute values (labels) e.g.:

```
my_new_list = ['(object_1, object_2)', '(object_3, object_1)', '(object_4, object_1)', '(object_2,)', ...]
```

I have looked up how to [extract a list of attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739800/extract-list-of-attributes-from-list-of-objects-in-python) from a list of objects and how to [convert a tuple to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525399/python-converting-from-tuple-to-string) and would probably achieve my goal with some nested for loops. But I got stuck in some messy code here..

But isn't there some nice pythonic way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

*EDIT: Some of the tuples are one dimensional e.g. `(obj2,)`. Sorry, I forgot that and now have adapted my question!

Comment: What's wrong with a standard list comprehension here?

Comment: It's not the objects only but the attributes within the string representation of the tuples.

Comment: As a general tip you can usually see the structure of the comprehension just by writing it out with actual for loops. In this case you'd write `for obj1, obj2 in my_list` to bring out the tuples, and then append `'(%s,%s)' % (obj1.label, obj2.label)` to an initially empty list. And you can see that same structure in the answers below. Edit: Just saw the edit. Same general principle applies.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your tip!

Comment: I added a more general answer not using nested comprehensions that I think reads nicely and is standard python. It's a great practice to give your classes good string representations with a `__repr__` function so they can be used in a manner like this. `print(my_obj)` is just nicer than `print(my_obj.label)` if the label makes sense to be the...well...label of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two other simple list comprehension answers work fine for an arbitrary list of tuples of objects with the attribute. However, Python has some great built-in functionality which let you choose the string representation of your objects, and most built-in types have this already. For example, any `tuple` can be cast to it's string representation just by encasing the `tuple` with `str(tuple)`:

```
>>> str((5, 4))
'(5, 4)'
```

Now, if you did this with a tuple of arbitrary objects, then you'd get a string which has the actual object handle like `<__main__.YourClass object at 0x10ad58fd0>` which is ugly. But, if you provide a `__repr__` function inside your class definition, then you can change that standard handle to something you like instead. In this case, your `label` seems like a good candidate to return for the string representation of your object. Here's a minimal example created with your same code:

```
class LabeledObj:

    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.label


obj1 = LabeledObj('object_1')
obj2 = LabeledObj('object_2')
obj3 = LabeledObj('object_3')
obj4 = LabeledObj('object_4')

my_list = [(obj1, obj2), (obj3, obj1), (obj4, obj1), (obj2,)]

my_new_list = [str(obj_tuple) for obj_tuple in my_list]
print(my_new_list)
```

> ['(object_1, object_2)', '(object_3, object_1)', '(object_4, object_1)', '(object_2,)']

Now I think *this* is very pythonic and very clear later in the code, and defining the `__repr__` only takes an additional two lines of code. And now you can `print(my_obj)` instead of `print(my_obj.label)` which reads nicely.

Comment: I guess this is the cleanest solution. Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
["(%s, %s)" %(i.label, j.label) for i, j in my_list]
```

If dynamic length inside tuple:

```
["(%s)" %", ".join([j.label for j in i]) for i in my_list]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a really nice solution. Unfortunately, I forgot one detail: The tuples are sometimes of dimension one e.g. `(obj1,)`. I will adapt my question. Sorry!

Comment: @CordKaldemeyer Edited the answer

Comment: Works like a charm! You saved my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html) for that:

```
['({}, {})'.format(el1.label, el2.label) for el1, el2 in my_list]
```

To not depend from tuple dimension use helper function:

```
def tuple_print(tup):
    return '({})'.format(', '.join(t.label for t in tup))

my_new_list = [tuple_print(tup) for tup in my_list]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer which looks nice as well. Unfortunately, I have forgotten to mention that the tuples differ in their dimension..

Comment: Edit my answer. Note that I use python3

Answer (score 1):

Tuple list elements count
using len() + generator expression

```
temp = list((int(j) for i in test_list for j in i)) 
res = len(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` function to help. This can be complete in one line of code

`my_new_list = list(map(lambda P: '({})'.format(','.join(list(map(lambda t:t.label,list(P))))),my_list))`

This also work with one dimension tuples.